# Do struct allocations' weight consumption depend linearly on input data length?

Tags: benchmarking

I am writing some benchmarking code and I came across a situation where I had to benchmark a few `let` bindings.

```rs
let sig = ...;
let data : Vec<u8> = vec![...];
// data is actually variable. Ranges from 0 bytes to 200k bytes
let tx = Transaction { ..., data };
```

If I put this code in a `#[block]` and benchmark it I get a constant number: `222_000`.
However. If I benchmark it using `Linear<1, 200_000>` I will get a linear dependence on length `400_000 + 10.saturating_mul(x)`.

I took care to not put the `vec![]` allocation inside the benchmark `#[block]`. Basically what you see in the code-snip above is also inside `#[block]`.

What surprises me now is that if the vec allocation is happening outside, why should the vector length matter when creating a `let` binding?

Doing the math on both, including the linear component gives me a 3-5x increase in estimated weight which I consider significant enough to warrant a question. Would love if someone can explain me the apparent discrepancy that I see here.

Comment: For these kinds of questions around the output of benchmarks, it is best to start looking at the raw data, not just the linear forumula that is outputted. Configure your benchmarks with the `json_file` flag, and graph the results. Usually these questions can answer themselves.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi thanks I didn't know about `json_file`. It helped me answer the question.

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, please write down the steps you took to solve it and what the solution was, that way others with a similar problem can get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I was expecting, `let` bindings shouldn't have a significant effect on benchmarking depending on the the vector size as in this particular case, the vector allocation was being done elsewhere (not being benchmarked). Just to be sure that this was the case and to find out the cause of getting a small linear correlation on data length, I ran the benchmarks with `json_file`, and noted that there was no dependence, but only minor outliers that were causing the benchmarking framework to falsely think that there was a linear upwards correlation. The `extrinsic` time and `storage_root_time` remained unchanged with the datum size.